# Intermittent fails random test with "Cannot read property 'body' of null" in react jest library for test

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs, continuous-integration, cicd

All tests are passing successfully locally but it intermittently fails random tests in `CI/CD` pipeline with the same error `Cannot read property 'body' of null`. and it pointed out some third file that was not used in the test case

Here is the error

```
Summary of all failing tests
2022-11-16T09:54:22.7643575Z FAIL src/components/__tests__/SearchDishResultDetail.spec.tsx (5.037 s)
2022-11-16T09:54:22.7644466Z   ● SearchDishResultDetail› renders correctly
2022-11-16T09:54:22.7644747Z 
2022-11-16T09:54:22.7645262Z     TypeError: Cannot read property 'body' of null
2022-11-16T09:54:22.7645517Z 
2022-11-16T09:54:22.7645835Z       263 |         !isUserVerified(UserDetails)
2022-11-16T09:54:22.7646556Z     > 264 |       ) {
2022-11-16T09:54:22.7646866Z           |       ^
2022-11-16T09:54:22.7647168Z       265 |         return;
2022-11-16T09:54:22.7647468Z       266 |       }
2022-11-16T09:54:22.7647869Z       267 |       const preferredAddressList = UserDetails.address.map(
2022-11-16T09:54:22.7648150Z 
2022-11-16T09:54:22.7648743Z       at getActiveElement (node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:6651:16)
2022-11-16T09:54:22.7649477Z       at getActiveElementDeep (node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:6939:17)
2022-11-16T09:54:22.7650226Z       at getSelectionInformation (node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:6972:21)
2022-11-16T09:54:22.7651136Z       at prepareForCommit (node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:7463:26)
2022-11-16T09:54:22.7651860Z       at commitRootImpl (node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:22474:5)
2022-11-16T09:54:22.7656503Z       at unstable_runWithPriority (node_modules/scheduler/cjs/scheduler.development.js:653:12)
2022-11-16T09:54:22.7657351Z       at runWithPriority$1 (node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:11039:10)
2022-11-16T09:54:22.7658084Z       at commitRoot (node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:22381:3)
2022-11-16T09:54:22.7928369Z       at finishSyncRender (node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:21807:3)
2022-11-16T09:54:22.7929476Z       at performSyncWorkOnRoot (node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:21793:7)
2022-11-16T09:54:22.7930268Z       at node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:11089:24
2022-11-16T09:54:22.7930898Z       at unstable_runWithPriority (node_modules/scheduler/cjs/scheduler.development.js:653:12)
2022-11-16T09:54:22.7931715Z       at runWithPriority$1 (node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:11039:10)
2022-11-16T09:54:22.7932554Z       at flushSyncCallbackQueueImpl (node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:11084:7)
2022-11-16T09:54:22.7933379Z       at flushSyncCallbackQueue (node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:11072:3)
2022-11-16T09:54:22.7934418Z       at scheduleUpdateOnFiber (node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:21199:9)
2022-11-16T09:54:22.7935218Z       at dispatchAction (node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:15660:5)
2022-11-16T09:54:22.7935899Z       at Timeout._onTimeout (src/components/UserProfile/UserProfile.tsx:264:7)
```

here Fails different test and pointed error is a different file which is not used directly or indirecctly in this file

Comment: Can you give us more context? An image or trace of the error and packages that you're using?

Comment: Are you mocking the REST API calls? Do you have a running back-end so that it works when you run it locally?